# Devise + Omniauth + fb_graph + Rails 3 Tutorial

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth, fb-graph

Can anyone suggest a good and complete tutorial on how to set up Facebook authentication with Devise and Omniauth in Rails 3, and then integrate it with Facebook Graph API using fb_graph?

I have already looked into Ryan Bates' railscasts and tons of other tutorials, but none of them seem to work. Any kind of help regarding this matter will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

lok to the below link
[FbGraph + OmniAuth + Facebook Graph API on Rails application](http://www.catespotr.com/2012/02/fbgraph-omniauth-facebook-graph-api-on.html)

Comment: WTF is up with the music on that site.